# PayPal - Need Payments Pro to Test Mass Pay?

Tags: authentication, paypal, masspay

This seems like an easy question, but as a developer do I need payments pro on my business account to test out the mass pay API for a client? The app will eventually sit on their PayPal account and they have payments pro. Asking because I keep getting authentication errors and thought it may be because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your customer's PayPal account needs to get approved for Mass Payments, then they need to give you third party Mass Payments permissions.  And you call the Mass Payments API on your customer's behalf.  They just need to contact PayPal CS to get the approval process started.